# Why only mitochondria and plastids?

Tags: cell-biology, symbiosis

Why are there only two unique semi-independent organelles? Why are there no others, symbiogenesis seems like it should be a relatively common thing. So do most organelles just lose all their DNA? Or is it something that occurs fairly rarely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are. But they are not that universal. See [kappa-particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappa_organism) in *Paramecium* and *[Wolbachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolbachia)* in insects. Also, there are different origins of plastids (compare red algae and green algae). Some organisms like [*Rhopallodia gibba*](http://mbe.oxfordjournals.org/content/21/8/1477.full) even have plastids of multiple origin.

> So do most organelles just lose all their DNA? Or is it something that
>   occurs fairly rarely?

The organelles of endosymbiotic origin lose their genes gradually. The extent and rate of loss is correlated with the number of organelle the cell harbours. The [limited transfer window hypothesis](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/38954/evolution-of-endosymbionts/38956#38956) speculates a probable mechanism.